# How to display the contain of an array in php which is in loop

Tags: php, html

I m stuck in a part where there is a loop and I want different contain with different statement

**buy 50 (statement 1)**

**rent 60 (statement 2)**

the code I have is like

```
 <?php if ($option['type'] == 'radio') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option form-group">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?> <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?><span class="required">*</span>:</b><?php } ?>
         <div class="checkbox-list">
          <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
          <label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>">
          <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"/>
          <?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
          <?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
            <?php } ?>
```

just wanted the two out not in the loop it use array which is confusing me

Comment: Please clarify your question..and provide some more code..

Comment: I agree with @KedarB This question needs much more details.

Comment: I m using many other php file with this php file also I m not able to find the contain of the variable/array **$option **...@kedarB @jkushner

Answer (score 0):

Incomplete php brackets lead to syntax error

```
<?php
$option = array('type'=>'radio','required'=>1,'name'=>'qwqw','option_value'=>array(array('product_option_value_id'=>0,'product_option_id'=>0,'name'=>'gdf','price'=>''),array('product_option_value_id'=>1,'product_option_id'=>1,'name'=>'gsgdgr','price'=>'$21') ) );
if ($option['type'] == 'radio') { ?>
    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option form-group">
    <?php if ($option['required']) { ?> <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?><span class="required">*</span>:</b><?php }; ?>
    <div class="checkbox-list">
    <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
        <label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>">
        <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"/>
        <?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
        <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Sorry but your code is not in a very good style(atleast I think so). First form complete html using php and then echo it at once rather than echoing it for each line

While posting in stackoverflow, please provide all the essential details too(in this case $option array format which I have built based on the breadcrumbs left)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct but this excrated part of a page ..some one already have worked on it and now m not able to figure out the problem is how this segment is working

```
<?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?> <label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"> <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"/> <?php echo $option_value['name']; ?> <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?> (<?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>) <?php } ?>
```

Comment: last `<?php } ?>` is for ending `if` block and two more brackets are required for ending `foreach` block and `if ($option['type'] == 'radio') { ?>` block. I have completed that part in the code I have answered, try it and let me know.